# Use HDD in both WIndows and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, games

I have only 1 hard disk.
I want to use a hard disk partition in both ubuntu and win10.
As i cant play good real hardcore games on ubuntu i have installed an operating system called windows 10 to play games.

Now my internet speed sucks it takes >=5 hours to download a rockstar game known as the GTAV.

Now the time im using ubuntu i want to download games and store it in a hard disk.
Then when its done. i want to go back to windows and install and play it.

So my question is what format do i format my hard disk and from which OS i format it ?
I have lots of unallocated space right now.  i want to use that to create a partition which will be used in both ubuntu and an OS called win10 by company known as microsoft founded by bill gates. 
So what options do i choose and from which os do i create partition ?

Thanks after giving advice no advance.

Comment: Ubuntu can read NTFS file systems, so you can just mount your Windows partition from Ubuntu and move the downloaded files there. You can normally (except by installing special drivers) not access Ubuntu's ext4 file systems from Windows though. If you want, you can also create a shared partition which both systems can use, either in NTFS or e.g. FAT32, depending on your needs. I'd just go for directly mounting the Windows partition in Ubuntu though.

Comment: exFAT would also be a good choice for a shared partition.

Comment: @ByteCommander ok so NTFS it is. and do i format it from windows or ubuntu's gparted or it dosent matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: yeah i did whatchu said now im getting `The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume` thanks for that now fix it kindly! opens in windows not in ubuntu. @ByteCommander

Comment: No need for that offensive tone. As the message says, you can not mount the Windows partition writeable (just read-only) if Windows is in a hibernating state. In recent Windows versions, the fast-boot option, which is enabled by default, makes it do some kind of mixture between shutdown and hibernation instead of a clean shutdown. So to access the Windows partition from Ubuntu, you have to disable Windows' fast-boot option and shut it down cleanly.